# Фамиия Бунин

Tags: этимология, ономастика

Задумалась: а от какого слова может происходить фамилия Бунин?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашла в "Каталоге фамилий" http://www.genway.ru/  :

Бунин
Анализ фамилии:
В 40% такие фамилии имеют русское происхождение, в 5% - белорусское, в 5% - украинское, в 25% приходят из языков народов России (татарского, мордовского, башкирского, бурятского и др.), в 20% имеют еврейские корни, в 20% являются русифицированными вариантами латышских фамилий. Эти фамилии почти всегда происходят от имени, прозвища или профессии дальнего предка её носителя, причём в 57% случаев – по мужской линии и в 40% случаев – по женской.

Значение, происхождение и история фамилии:

БУНИН

Буня - спесивый, гордый человек. Было ивыражение 'Буня-дутик' (Ф). Отчество от прозвища Буня из диалектного глагола бунить - 'гудеть, мычать, реветь'. В.И.Даль привел рязанско-тамбовское слово буня - 'спесивый, чванный', но отметил это значение знаком вопроса. (Н) Бунилин из Бунила, веротно, от той же основы.